# Custom Transformer and FeatureUnion for word2vec

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, pipeline, word2vec

I am trying to classify a set of text documents using multiple sets of features. I am using [sklearn's Feature Union](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-hetero-feature-union-py) to combine different features for fitting into a single model. One of the features includes word embeddings using [gensim's word2vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html).

```
import numpy as np
from gensim.models.word2vec import Word2Vec
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest

categories = ['alt.atheism', 'talk.religion.misc', 'comp.graphics', 'sci.space']
data = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', categories=categories)#dummy dataset

w2v_model= Word2Vec(data .data, size=100, window=5, min_count=5, workers=2)
word2vec={w: vec for w, vec in zip(w2v_model.wv.index2word, w2v_model.wv.syn0)} #dictionary of word embeddings
feat_select = SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k=10) #other features
TSVD = TruncatedSVD(n_components=50, algorithm = "randomized", n_iter = 5)
#other features
```

In order to include transformers/estimators not already available in sklearn, I am attempting to wrap my word2vec results into a custom transformer class that returns the vector averages.

```
class w2vTransformer(TransformerMixin):
    """
    Wrapper class for running word2vec into pipelines and FeatureUnions
    """
    def __init__(self,word2vec,**kwargs):
        self.word2vec=word2vec
        self.kwargs=kwargs
        self.dim = len(word2vec.values())
    def fit(self,x, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return np.array([
        np.mean([self.word2vec[w] for w in words if w in self.word2vec] 
            or [np.zeros(self.dim)], axis=0)
       for words in X
])
```

However when it comes time to fit the model I receive an error.

```
combined_features = FeatureUnion([("w2v_class",w2vTransformer(word2vec)),
     ("feat",feat_select),("TSVD",TSVD)])#join features into combined_features
#combined_features = FeatureUnion([("feat",feat_select),("TSVD",TSVD)])#runs when word embeddings are not included    
text_clf_svm = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),
         ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
         ('feature_selection', combined_features),
          ('clf-svm',  SGDClassifier( loss="modified_huber")),
 ]) 

text_clf_svm_1 = text_clf_svm.fit(data.data,data.target) # fits data

text_clf_svm_1 = text_clf_svm.fit(data.data,data.target) # fits data
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-8-a085b7d40f8f>", line 1, in <module>
    text_clf_svm_1 = text_clf_svm.fit(data.data,data.target) # fits data

  File "C:\Users\rlusk\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 248, in fit
    Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)

  File "C:\Users\rlusk\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 213, in _fit
    **fit_params_steps[name])

  File "C:\Users\rlusk\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\memory.py", line 362, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\rlusk\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 581, in _fit_transform_one
    res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)

  File "C:\Users\rlusk\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 739, in fit_transform
    for name, trans, weight in self._iter())

  File "C:\Users\rlusk\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 779, in __call__
    while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):

  File "C:\Users\rlusk\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 625, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)

  File "C:\Users\rlusk\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 588, in _dispatch
    job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)

  File "C:\Users\rlusk\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 111, in apply_async
    result = ImmediateResult(func)

  File "C:\Users\rlusk\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 332, in __init__
    self.results = batch()

  File "C:\Users\rlusk\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 131, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]

  File "C:\Users\rlusk\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 131, in <listcomp>
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]

  File "C:\Users\rlusk\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 581, in _fit_transform_one
    res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)

  File "C:\Users\rlusk\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 520, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

  File "<ipython-input-6-cbc52cd420cd>", line 16, in transform
    for words in X

  File "<ipython-input-6-cbc52cd420cd>", line 16, in <listcomp>
    for words in X

  File "<ipython-input-6-cbc52cd420cd>", line 14, in <listcomp>
    np.mean([self.word2vec[w] for w in words if w in self.word2vec]

TypeError: unhashable type: 'csr_matrix'

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-8-a085b7d40f8f>", line 1, in <module>
    text_clf_svm_1 = text_clf_svm.fit(data.data,data.target) # fits data

  File "C:\Users\rlusk\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 248, in fit
    Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)

  File "C:\Users\rlusk\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 213, in _fit
    **fit_params_steps[name])

  File "C:\Users\rlusk\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\memory.py", line 362, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\rlusk\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 581, in _fit_transform_one
    res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)

  File "C:\Users\rlusk\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 739, in fit_transform
    for name, trans, weight in self._iter())

  File "C:\Users\rlusk\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 779, in __call__
    while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):

  File "C:\Users\rlusk\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 625, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)

  File "C:\Users\rlusk\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 588, in _dispatch
    job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)

  File "C:\Users\rlusk\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 111, in apply_async
    result = ImmediateResult(func)

  File "C:\Users\rlusk\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 332, in __init__
    self.results = batch()

  File "C:\Users\rlusk\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 131, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]

  File "C:\Users\rlusk\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 131, in <listcomp>
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]

  File "C:\Users\rlusk\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 581, in _fit_transform_one
    res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)

  File "C:\Users\rlusk\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 520, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

  File "<ipython-input-6-cbc52cd420cd>", line 16, in transform
    for words in X

  File "<ipython-input-6-cbc52cd420cd>", line 16, in <listcomp>
    for words in X

  File "<ipython-input-6-cbc52cd420cd>", line 14, in <listcomp>
    np.mean([self.word2vec[w] for w in words if w in self.word2vec]

TypeError: unhashable type: 'csr_matrix'
```

I understand that the error is because the variable "words" is a csr_matrix, but it needs to be an iterable such as a list. My question is how do I modify the transformer class or data so I can use the word embeddings as features to feed into FeatureUnion? This is my first SO post, please be gentle.

Comment: The above code is working without any errors in my system. Are you sure this is the complete and same code which is giving you errors. Also try upgrading all libraries you are using.

Comment: I did fail to include a couple package dependencies in the code, code has been updated. Just updated my packages, still receiving the same error.

Comment: Still no error on my system.

Comment: I can see in the error trace the line `text_clf_svm.fit(training_set.Abstract,training_set.AbKeep)` , but the code you have given above is for `text_clf_svm_1 = text_clf_svm.fit(data.data,data.target)`.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 14, with Python 2.7.6 and NumPy - 1.13.3, SciPy - 0.19.1 and Scikit-Learn - 0.19.0. If that helps.

Comment: apologies, updated traceback now using dummy data.

Comment: I have also rolled back my package versions to be for Numpy - 1.13.3 Scipy 0.19.1 and Scikit-Learn 0.19.0, still receiving the same error. I am running in Python 3.6.3

Comment: Ok. Can confirm this error occurs in Python3 with same packages, but on python2 runs without errors.

Comment: Confirmed. Running in python2 the code above runs fine. Not sure what the underlying issue is, but thanks for your help troubleshooting

Comment: Please post this as an issue to scikit-learn github page. They will either look at it or forward it to appropriate page.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your custom transformer you can avoid the bug using the new scikit-learn API directly provided by Gensim! https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/sklearn_api/w2vmodel.html

Also, it depends on your version of Gensim, but in my case I could solve the same bug using the wv attribute of your word2vec object, instead of indexing on the object itself.

In the transform method of your w2vTransformer class:

```
self.word2vec.wv[w]
```

instead of

```
self.word2vec[w]
```

Hope it helps!